# Want to deploy Solr 4.0.0 on JBoss 6.0.1

Tags: solr, solrj, solr4

I am new for Solr installation on JBoss. Can anyone help me to deploy Solr 4.0.0 on JBoss 6.0.1?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Could you tell us what you have tried so far? Your question is very broad and it's hard to tell if you have done any effort at researching it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the instructions to install Solr in JBoss in the "official" solr documentation (http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrJBoss). In general installing Solr in any Container/Application Server consists of deploying the "war" file in the deployment directory (in jboss "deployment" directory of the installation), then define the environment variable "solr.solr.home" and "solr.data.dir", which should point for the directory where you have your "solr" (where you extracted/placed your Solr distribution) - you can define these in the "JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml" file, like this:

```
<system-properties>
  <property name="solr.solr.home" value="/usr/local/jboss/solr/solr-4.2.1"/>
  <property name="solr.data.dir" value="/usr/local/jboss/solr/data"/>
  <property name="org.apache.catalina.connector.URI_ENCODING" value="UTF-8"/>
  <property name="org.apache.catalina.connector.USE_BODY_ENCODING_FOR_QUERY_STRING" value="true"/>
</system-properties>
```